# HERE traffic api - Getting historical traffic data

Tags: here-api, traffic, here-maps-rest, heremaps, here-traffic

I would like to get a traffic data map tile for a specific time. To do this,
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-traffic-flowbasetile.html as written in the documentation, I passed the "time" parameter. however, it looks like it does not work properly.

Requested example URL:
https://1.traffic.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/traffictile/newest/normal.day/13/4358/2842/512/png?apiKey=apikey&ppi=500&time=2021-08-03T16:00:00Z

[image]

The response of real time traffic data on 2021-09-21T16:31:00z. I got this result without passing time parameter at exactly this time 2021-09-21T16:31:00z.

```
https://1.traffic.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/traffictile/newest/normal.day/13/4358/2842/512/png?apiKey={apikey}&ppi=500
```

[image]

The response of data when I passed the time parameter.

```
https://1.traffic.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/traffictile/newest/normal.day/13/4358/2842/512/png?apiKey={apikey}&ppi=500&time=2021-09-21T16:31:00z
```

As I tested the historical data response with my already saved response(when i requested to realtime traffic data) they are not same. Historical traffic data always returns similar response with little changes but they are not right.
It even returns result for future dates like 2022. Is the API broken? It works for realtime traffic data but has problems when i specify the time.

Answer (score 1):

In Here Map Tile V2, you need to pass a timestamp after 2009, as a time before the year 2009 is not supported. For rest, the historical traffic data tile works well.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your request you should not use a time before year 2009 as this is not supported.

Response with **Time** parameter --

```
https://1.traffic.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/traffictile/newest/normal.day/13/4358/2842/512/png?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}&ppi=500&time=2021-09-13T16:00:00z
```

[image]

Also please check the documentation for your reference.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-traffic-traffictile.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, as I edited my question and added response pictures, here API always returns a similar traffic tile for all days, and they are different than the traffic tile data I get from real-time API. I think there is something wrong with getting historical data.